# Can anyone explain me what replaces CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL in iOS9?

Tags: swift, ftp

I'm trying to make a `FTP` connection in Swift using `CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL`, but it is deprecated in iOS9.

Does anyone know whats the replacement is of that? 
Or if there is no replacement: how you can make an `ftp` connection.

It just need to do this: connect the user (after pressing on the connect button) with the `ftp` server `ftp.responsivewebsolutions.nl` with the username and password they filled in in the forms. If the connection is OK it needs to print that in the logs.

Comment: It does not appear a replacement is in the works: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9807